# Can't get test to run on Visual Studio 2019 using Microsoft CppUnitTest Framework

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I've a function `std::vector<Token> tokenize(const std::string& s)` that I want to unit test. The `Token` struct is defined as follows:

```cpp
enum class Token_type { plus, minus, mult, div, number };

struct Token {
    Token_type type;
    double value;
}
```

I have set up CppUnitTest and can get toy tests such as `1 + 1 == 2` to run. But when I try to run a test on my `tokenize` function it gives me this error:

```
Error C2338: Test writer must define specialization of ToString<const Q& q> for your class class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString<class std::vector<struct Token,class std::allocator<struct Token> >>(const class std::vector<struct Token,class std::allocator<struct Token> > &).
```

My testing code is this:

```
#include <vector>

#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

#include "../calc-cli/token.hpp"


using namespace std;

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;


namespace test_tokens {
    TEST_CLASS(test_tokenize) {
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(binary_operation_plus) {
            auto r = tokenize("1+2");
            vector<Token> s = {
                Token{ Token_type::number, 1.0 },
                Token{ Token_type::plus },
                Token{ Token_type::number, 2.0}
            };

            Assert::AreEqual(r, s);
        }
    };
}
```

What's causing the error and how can I fix this?

Comment: ¿Have you tried defining that specialization as compiler error suggests? It is required for printing results. Most likely `operator ==` should be provided as well.

Comment: @user7860670 I'm a beginner programmer and this is my first major C++ program. I'm afraid I don't know what a specialization is. From the web, I can see that I need to define a function `ToString` inside `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework`, but I can't figure out the correct signature and code. I should be able to if I see an example.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Assert::AreEqual` the framework wants to be able to display a string that describes the objects if the assert fails. It uses the templated function `ToString` for this, which includes specializations for all the basic data types. For any other data type, you would have to provide a specialization that knows how to format the data into a meaningful string.

The simplest solution is to use a different type of assert that doesn't require `ToString`. For example:

```
Assert::IsTrue(r == s, L"Some descriptive failure message");
```

The other option is to create the `ToString` specialization that the assert needs:

```
#include <CppUnitTestAssert.h>
namespace Microsoft {
    namespace VisualStudio {
        namespace CppUnitTestFramework {
            template<> static inline std::wstring ToString(const std::vector<Token> &t)
            {
                // Write some code here to create a descriptive std::wstring
                return std::wstring("My object description");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I would only go to the trouble of making a specialization if I'm going to be writing a lot of tests using that same object type, and I want to automatically describe the objects.